# Keyboard does not work when connecting via remote desktop connection manager

Tags: keyboard, connection, desktop, remote

can someone assist me, I am unable to use the keyboard when connecting to any machine or server when connecting via remote desktop connection manager.

My main Local machine is an Apple Mac.
I am connecting to a server 2008r2 virtual machine.

the mouse works perfect, it is just the keyboard that does not work.

Please assist asap

Answer (score 0):

You need to use keyboard-layout that's one of the native languages or the conversion from, lets say Canadian (English) to remote-desktops keyboard-layout, causes problems with it.

Try English (US) instead of your current one or even better, use the same as the remote desktop one. If they're same, make sure they're both one of the native ones.